# How to add RequiredFieldValidator control with ValidationExpression in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

it seems RequiredFieldValidator does not have a ValidationExpression in code behind...
or I'am missing something.

In design view I can set the property.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^(.|\n){3,2000}$" ... />
```

How can I set the ValidationExpression property on code behind?

```
var validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
validator. ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instatiation a RequiredFieldValidator and not a ReqularExpressionValidator

Try this

```
RegularExpressionValidator regExpressionValidator = new RegularExpressionValidator();
regExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

ValidationExpression property does not exist in RequiredFieldValidator, so you can't set this property. Actually, this property exists for RegularExpressionValidator.

In design view you can do this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

In CodeBehind:

```
RegularExpressionValidator1.ValidationExpression = "your validation expression";
```

Hope this help you.
Cheers.